# Set focus on first item of the suggestions list displayed in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to customize `autocomplete` widget so that the first item of the suggestions list is selected by default, so that as soon as user hits `enter` the first item of the suggestions list is selected in the autocomplete.

How can I do that ?

---

I am **not using jquery's autocomplete directly** but through primefaces which doesnt provide option to specify autoFocus. Thus I would need to implement this autoFocus manually .

Can someone let me know how I can put the focus on the first item of  list even while typing in the input field

Answer (score 3):

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ autoFocus: true });
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-autoFocus

Comment: Thanks I would need to implement this autoFocus manually as I am not using jquery's autocomplete directly but through primefaces which doesnt provide this option to specify autoFocus

Comment: `$( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "autoFocus", true ); //setter` -- also in the documentation.